# I want to make NaOH from NaHCO3, what is the easiest way to do it without electrolysis?

Tags: home-experiment

I want to make NaOH from NaHCO3.
I can't use electrolysis as I lack the proper equipement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could heat it to turn bicarbonate into carbonate, and let it stand with Ca(OH2) and water mix. That's essentialy how potash lye was made for millenia

Comment: How hot though?

Comment: Look for decomposition temperature of nahco3 on wikipedia. You will see gas pops in the powder once you've reached the temperature, heat untill they stop appearing

Comment: The CO2 bubbles?

Comment: Wikipedia says 100°C